# How to fill a list with dict of keys in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have this inventory dict and an empty items list that I want to fill it with the keys in the inventory dict. Any clues on how do I fill the list?

```
# Inventory Dict
inventory = {}
inventory["item a"] = 12
inventory["item b"] = 10
inventory["item x"] = 25
print(inventory)

# Item List
items = []
```

Comment: `items = list(inventory.keys())`

Comment: have a read of https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Comment: How if I want to in a loop that fills the list with dict's keys?

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops/3294899#3294899

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items = list(inventory.keys())
```

or in a loop (as requested)

```
for key in inventory:
    items.append(key)
```

though as is there's no need for the loop. Perhaps there would be in another situation